# Connectivity comparison between chess websites?

Tags: lichess, websites, chess.com

I wonder if there has been a test to compare connectivity to the major chess websites. Or whether it is easy to run such a test myself if needed.

Here is what I mean to test:

I am mainly playing on two websites (lichess.org and chess.com) and one one of these it frequently feels like I 'lose' seconds. Maybe it is only 1-5 seconds per time, and only once or twice per game, but still it adds up.

I notice this only on one of these sites which makes me suspect it could be server side rather than my personal wifi and such. However, maybe it is a matter of perception, hence my interest in a benchmark or test.

In case it is relevant:

- In both cases I mostly use the mobile web version from my android phone
- I am located near Amsterdam
- Outside the games I do not notice any slowness on the sites

---

### What have I tried?

I ran the ping app on my phone, actually the site where I notice the weird behavior has lower ping time (but neither of them comes close to 1000ms), so I suspect it may not be a general connection issue but rather something that happens when playing games.

Comment: I couldn't find a source right now but afaik premoves differ. In lichess you almost don't lose time on premoves where in chess.com you lose a couple miliseconds even if you premove. But this probably doesn't explain 1-5 seconds delay you mentioned. Edit: There is [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/frpw9d/do_premoves_on_chesscom_use_some_of_the_clock/) reddit post.

Comment: @Minot You lose 0.1 seconds per premove on chess.com (by design). It's nothing to do with connectivity.

Comment: Do you mean you use the web version from a browser in your phone? In that case consider trying the apps.

Comment: I will consider the app, but am still curious as to whether there is a way to measure 'in game latency spikes'

Comment: Switched to the app, and actually am seeing even much worse lag spikes where even if I premoved it sometimes costs me 4 sec, last game 3x. I understand this could be my local issue, but just want to measure the achieved connectivity difference between the sites in gameplay.

Comment: Lichess measures server lag [here](https://lichess.org/lag). [This chess.com](https://support.chess.com/article/357-what-is-lag-in-live-chess) article is also related, although it refers to players' problems

Comment: @MobeusZoom That's when you have a good connection. But if the connection is bad then the pre move time might take more than 0.1 s.

Answer (score 2):

You can check your ping on `lichess.org` by going [here](https://www.lichess.org/lag). For `chess.com`, you can type `/ping` in the chat when playing a game by going [here](https://www.chess.com/play/online).

A trick to check ping on the `chess.com` app. (Btw, I think it'll be the same on the app and website) Go to New game -> tournaments -> Daily -> Then in the top left you'll get the menu where you can go to Live chess page -> Type /ping in chat.

Edit: The Live server of `Chess.com` is in the primary data center in California. Following are the approximate ping for the regions on `chess.com`.

- 12 ms for US connections
- 156 ms for European connections
- 145 ms for Asia-Pacific connections

`Lichess's` server is located in France. So, the ping would be lower in European countries and higher in other continents.